# Is there a way to ignore calculating language statistics for a directory on Github?

Tags: github, github-linguist

I am currently creating a lot of small experimental game projects in Lua that include a framework written in C, which dominates the code percentages and declares my project as being in C when it is not.

I do however want to keep this framework, as it allows me to add on the playable version of the game.

I am partially familiar with the concept of removing language statistics on a file, but is there a way to omit a directory?

I have also seen most answers link to [this](https://github.com/github/linguist#overrides) answer but as I am new to github I don't quite know how to decipher it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to exclude files from git language statistics?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19052834/is-it-possible-to-exclude-files-from-git-language-statistics)

Answer (score 29):

To ignore all files from a particular directory when computing statistics, you can use the following `.gitattributes`:

```
your/framework/directory/* linguist-vendored
```

If you think your framework is common enough through github.com, you can make a pull request to [Linguist](https://github.com/github/linguist) to add it to the [list of ignored directories](https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/master/lib/linguist/vendor.yml). That way, you won't need to ignore it on a per-repository basis.

Answer (score 8):

This will ignore all the files in the given folder and subfolders from the stats.

`linguist-vendored`: This attribute helps us exclude files from stats.

In the `.gitattributes` file:

```
folder_to_ignore_files_from/** linguist-vendored
```

For e.g. I had a static_root folder in my root directory from which I wanted to ignore files from. So,

```
static_root/** linguist-vendored
```

I had created the `.gitattributes` in root directory.

Ref: [link](https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/master/docs/overrides.md#vendored-code)

Answer (score 1):

To give an example on an actual project, to disable [this](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/tree/master/Example/Resources) folder in the statistics of [Alamofire project](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire), the command would be:

```
Alamofire/Example/Resources/* linguist-vendored
```

inside the project's `.gitattributes` file.