# Ignore other library files in GitHub so they do not appear in project's (programming) Languages

Tags: c++, git, github, github-linguist

**Solution:**
Create `.gitattributes` in git folder and paste `linguist-languate=text` after the file path. Example:

```
/other_libraries/* linguist-language=text
/linguist_ignore.c linguist-language=text
```

Note: `linguist-vendored=false` didn't solve the problem. GitHub still detected marked files as **C** code.

**Problem:**

My C++/OpenGL project is compiled using `glad.c`, and `stb_imbage.h` is included in `mail.cpp` file. Both located in root folder which contains `.git` directory. These two files have to be present in order to compile the project, so I want to keep them.

Issue: GitHub indexes these files and adds them to *Language* statistic. It is undesirable since it is not the files containing *my* code.

How do I keep certain files tracked by Git but exclude them from *Languages*?

I've tried looking for solution in GitHub docs about *Linguist* and Stack Overflow but without success.

I know how to ignore files using `.gitignore`. But it's not the solution since ignored files just won't be commited.

Comment: My projects have some languages listed that have only a passing relevance to the bulk of the code. I can't recall, in all the years they were on Github, me caring even a little bit, or figuring out why I should even care in the first place, or what difference does it make. Can you explain what tangible problem this creates?

Comment: easiest solution is to live with it.  After all, those *are* in your repo, so the statistics are accurate, you just don't like them.

Comment: Those stats aren't about your code, it's about your repository. Not sure you can tell GitHub to ignore them for stats purposes.

Comment: One option could be to structure your build system to acquire the files, so that you don't have to commit them. cmake has fetch_content, or you could use Conan or vckpg manifest mode integration.

Comment: Try setting `linguist-vendored` attribute; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/70542975/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub-linguist%5D+ignore+files

Comment: Answering to all comments above. I want my repository to reflect **my work** that has been done. Just like other `include` files are not indexed by _Linguist_, the same way I want mentioned libraries not to be indexed as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GitHub uses [Linguist library](https://github.com/github/linguist) to generate the language stats.

At https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/master/docs/overrides.md you can read about the ways to override the default behavior using a `.gitattributes` file. It looks like the following section fits your case the most:

> ### Vendored code
>
> Checking code you didn't write, such as JavaScript libraries, into your git repo is a common practice, but this often inflates your project's language stats and may even cause your project to be labeled as another language. By default, Linguist treats all of the paths defined in vendor.yml as vendored and therefore doesn't include them in the language statistics for a repository.
>
> Use the linguist-vendored attribute to vendor or un-vendor paths:
>
> *(exmaple follows)*