# Linguist Documentation not working in github?

Tags: github, github-linguist

I recently studied about [.gitattributes](https://github.com/github/linguist#using-gitattributes) specifically [linguist-documentation](https://github.com/github/linguist#documentation.) and [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42544813/paths-not-excluded-from-github-language-statistics) But it does not work for me in this [repo](https://github.com/srilakshmikanthanp/art). It still counts HTML, CSS, and JavaScript files. Any suggestion to solve this ?

My [.gitattributes](https://github.com/srilakshmikanthanp/art/blob/master/.gitattributes) File

```
artcpp/docs/** linguist-documentation
artjava/docs/** linguist-documentation
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `.gitattributes` works fine. The issue is that you have a lot of other HTML files under `artjava/target/site/apidocs/`. See the full Linguist breakdown below.

---

```
$ github-linguist --breakdown
75.45%  HTML
11.08%  C++
4.30%   Java
3.91%   JavaScript
2.93%   Go
2.34%   CSS
0.01%   Shell

C++:
Fontcvt/CLI/converter/converter.hpp
Fontcvt/CLI/main/main.cpp
artcpp/example/example_1.cpp
artcpp/example/example_2.cpp
artcpp/example/example_3.cpp
artcpp/example/example_4.cpp
artcpp/include/art.hpp
artcpp/include/art/anixt/anixt_config.hpp
artcpp/include/art/anixt/anixt_font.hpp
artcpp/include/art/anixt/anixt_style.hpp
artcpp/include/art/anixt/basic_anixt.hpp
artcpp/include/art/coartl/coartl.hpp
artcpp/include/art/runeape/basic_runeape.hpp
artcpp/include/art/runeape/runeape_config.hpp
artcpp/include/art/runeape/runeape_gallery.hpp
artcpp/include/art/runeape/runeape_style.hpp

Go:
artgo/anixt/anixt.go
artgo/anixt/config.go
artgo/anixt/font.go
artgo/anixt/style.go
artgo/coartl/coartl.go
artgo/runeape/config.go
artgo/runeape/gallery.go
artgo/runeape/runeape.go
artgo/runeape/style.go

Shell:
artjava/package.sh

Java:
artjava/src/main/java/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/anixt/Anixt.java
artjava/src/main/java/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/anixt/Config.java
artjava/src/main/java/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/anixt/FontBase.java
artjava/src/main/java/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/anixt/JsonFont.java
artjava/src/main/java/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/anixt/KerningStyle.java
artjava/src/main/java/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/anixt/SmushedStyle.java
artjava/src/main/java/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/anixt/StyleBase.java
artjava/src/main/java/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/anixt/StyleUtil.java
artjava/src/main/java/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/anixt/UntouchedStyle.java
artjava/src/main/java/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/coartl/Coartl.java
artjava/src/main/java/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/runeape/Config.java
artjava/src/main/java/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/runeape/GalleryBase.java
artjava/src/main/java/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/runeape/JsonGallery.java
artjava/src/main/java/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/runeape/KerningStyle.java
artjava/src/main/java/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/runeape/Runeape.java
artjava/src/main/java/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/runeape/StyleBase.java
artjava/src/main/java/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/runeape/StyleUtil.java
artjava/src/main/java/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/runeape/UntouchedStyle.java
artjava/src/test/java/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/JsonFontTest.java
artjava/src/test/java/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/JsonGalleryTest.java
artjava/src/test/java/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/KerningAnixtStyleTest.java
artjava/src/test/java/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/KerningRuneapeTest.java
artjava/src/test/java/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/SmushingAnixtStyleTest.java
artjava/src/test/java/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/UntouchedAnixtStyleTest.java
artjava/src/test/java/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/UntouchedRuneapeStyleTest.java

HTML:
artjava/target/site/apidocs/allclasses-index.html
artjava/target/site/apidocs/allclasses.html
artjava/target/site/apidocs/allpackages-index.html
artjava/target/site/apidocs/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/anixt/Anixt.html
artjava/target/site/apidocs/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/anixt/Config.ShrinkLevel.html
artjava/target/site/apidocs/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/anixt/Config.html
artjava/target/site/apidocs/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/anixt/FontBase.html
artjava/target/site/apidocs/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/anixt/JsonFont.html
artjava/target/site/apidocs/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/anixt/KerningStyle.html
artjava/target/site/apidocs/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/anixt/SmushedStyle.html
artjava/target/site/apidocs/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/anixt/StyleBase.html
artjava/target/site/apidocs/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/anixt/StyleUtil.html
artjava/target/site/apidocs/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/anixt/UntouchedStyle.html
artjava/target/site/apidocs/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/anixt/class-use/Anixt.html
artjava/target/site/apidocs/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/anixt/class-use/Config.ShrinkLevel.html
artjava/target/site/apidocs/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/anixt/class-use/Config.html
artjava/target/site/apidocs/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/anixt/class-use/FontBase.html
artjava/target/site/apidocs/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/anixt/class-use/JsonFont.html
artjava/target/site/apidocs/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/anixt/class-use/KerningStyle.html
artjava/target/site/apidocs/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/anixt/class-use/SmushedStyle.html
artjava/target/site/apidocs/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/anixt/class-use/StyleBase.html
artjava/target/site/apidocs/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/anixt/class-use/StyleUtil.html
artjava/target/site/apidocs/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/anixt/class-use/UntouchedStyle.html
artjava/target/site/apidocs/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/anixt/package-summary.html
artjava/target/site/apidocs/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/anixt/package-tree.html
artjava/target/site/apidocs/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/anixt/package-use.html
artjava/target/site/apidocs/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/coartl/Coartl.html
artjava/target/site/apidocs/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/coartl/class-use/Coartl.html
artjava/target/site/apidocs/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/coartl/package-summary.html
artjava/target/site/apidocs/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/coartl/package-tree.html
artjava/target/site/apidocs/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/coartl/package-use.html
artjava/target/site/apidocs/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/runeape/Config.ShrinkLevel.html
artjava/target/site/apidocs/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/runeape/Config.html
artjava/target/site/apidocs/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/runeape/GalleryBase.html
artjava/target/site/apidocs/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/runeape/JsonGallery.html
artjava/target/site/apidocs/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/runeape/KerningStyle.html
artjava/target/site/apidocs/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/runeape/Runeape.html
artjava/target/site/apidocs/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/runeape/StyleBase.html
artjava/target/site/apidocs/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/runeape/StyleUtil.html
artjava/target/site/apidocs/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/runeape/UntouchedStyle.html
artjava/target/site/apidocs/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/runeape/class-use/Config.ShrinkLevel.html
artjava/target/site/apidocs/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/runeape/class-use/Config.html
artjava/target/site/apidocs/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/runeape/class-use/GalleryBase.html
artjava/target/site/apidocs/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/runeape/class-use/JsonGallery.html
artjava/target/site/apidocs/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/runeape/class-use/KerningStyle.html
artjava/target/site/apidocs/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/runeape/class-use/Runeape.html
artjava/target/site/apidocs/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/runeape/class-use/StyleBase.html
artjava/target/site/apidocs/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/runeape/class-use/StyleUtil.html
artjava/target/site/apidocs/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/runeape/class-use/UntouchedStyle.html
artjava/target/site/apidocs/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/runeape/package-summary.html
artjava/target/site/apidocs/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/runeape/package-tree.html
artjava/target/site/apidocs/com/github/srilakshmikanthanp/art/runeape/package-use.html
artjava/target/site/apidocs/constant-values.html
artjava/target/site/apidocs/deprecated-list.html
artjava/target/site/apidocs/help-doc.html
artjava/target/site/apidocs/index-all.html
artjava/target/site/apidocs/index.html
artjava/target/site/apidocs/overview-summary.html
artjava/target/site/apidocs/overview-tree.html
artjava/target/site/apidocs/serialized-form.html

JavaScript:
artjava/target/site/apidocs/jquery/jquery-migrate-3.0.1.js
artjava/target/site/apidocs/script.js
artjava/target/site/apidocs/search.js

CSS:
artjava/target/site/apidocs/stylesheet.css
```