# Is there a way to see the code composition of my projects?

Tags: github, portfolio

GitHub has a feature where it can show you which languages your projects use with a percentage.

However, due to large JS packages it is mostly showing as JavaScript.

Is there a way I can I can see the code composition for my projects individually, even if it's not on GitHub? I'm trying to use it for my portfolio.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean _"due to large JS packages"_? Are you storing your _dependencies_ in source control?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Maybe my terminology is not 100% correct. What I mean is that I have large downloads in my Repositiory such as leaflet.js, jquery.js and a few more.

Comment: Yes, those are _dependencies_. If you want accurate numbers for what you actually wrote, you should only be storing source code in GitHub, then dependencies can be pulled in (using tools like NPM, Yarn) at build time.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I would do that as it's a good suggestion but for my projects I'm not allowed to have any external dependencies. They must all be in my repositiory.

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19052834/is-it-possible-to-exclude-files-from-git-language-statistics then.